# Can't retrieve associative array index in php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, associative

I have an array that looks like the following:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) 
{ 
["habitacionales"]=> array(1) 
{ ["Azcapotzalco"]=> string(1) "3" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["comerciales"]=> array(0) { } } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["industriales"]=> array(0) { } }
}
```

And I need to check if the array belongs to the type "habitacionales", or "comerciales", etc. But no matter what I do, I keep getting the notice "Undefined index: habitacionales". Could someone point out how to access that index?

I am using cakephp, and I am setting the variables in the controller like this:

```
$zonasHab = $this->PropiedadesHabitacionale->BasicosPropiedadesHabitacionale->find('list', array('fields'=>array('Zona', 'propiedad_habitacional_id')));
```

then I do:

```
$this->set('Zonas', array_unique($linksZonas, SORT_REGULAR));
```

And finally in the view I do:

```
foreach ($Zonas as $zona) {
                        foreach($zona as $zone) {
                        foreach(array_flip($zone) as $link)   {
                        echo '<li   class="dropdownheader">'.$link;
                        }


                        var_dump($zone['habitacionales']);
                        }/*
                        if($zona['habitacionales']!=null) 
                        foreach(array_flip($zone) as $vinculo) {
                        echo '<li>'.$this->Html- >link($vinculo, array('controller'=>'propiedadeshabitacionales', 'action'=>'ver', $vinculo)).'</li>';
                        }
                        */
                        echo '</li>'; 
}
```

Just to point out, the wierd thing is that if I do `var_dump($zona['habitacionales']);` inside the outer `foreach`, I get the correct value: array(1) { ["Azcapotzalco"]=> string(1) "3" } but I still get the notice appearing telling me it's an undefined index, and I can't use that same syntax ($zona['habitacionales'] for a condition or anything else.

Comment: the example you give at the beginning of your question, did you get it by `var_dump`ing the `$Zonas` array?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $Zonas is that array above, try:

```
foreach($zona as $zone) {
                    foreach(array_flip($zone) as $link)   {
                    echo '<li   class="dropdownheader">'.$link;
                    }


                    var_dump($zone);
```

habitacionales is the key, if you want to access that then use:

```
foreach($zona as $key => $zone) {
```

And $key should be set to habitacionales.